# Make IIS not render pages as WML. Ever!

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

**Some background**

I'm currently working on a mobile site so I keep switching user agent all the time in Firefox with [User Agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) (lovely addon). But when I go to the admin site it renders as [WML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Markup_Language), which makes Firefox all confused, so it tries to download it rather then showing the content. And this makes me frustrated (not falling down frustrated, but enough!).

**What I want!**

How can I make our admin site to ALWAYS send content as `text/html` instead of WML, regardless of request user-agent?

I have full control of the box. It's IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a no-code/no-aspx change, you can add a browser capabilities file into the folder App_Browsers directly under your application root (if the folder's not there, just create it). To disable WML, simply put a file named ForceHtml.browser (anything ending in .browser) containing the following XML:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="preferredRenderingMime" value="text/html" />
      <capability name="preferredRenderingType" value="html32" />
      <capability name="preferredImageMime" value="image/gif" />
      <capability name="tagwriter" value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
    </capabilities>
    <controlAdapters markupTextWriterType="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Answer (score 12):

[We had this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87134/receiving-content-type-text-vnd-wap-wml-from-stack-overflow-when-logged-out/90459#90459), and since we are using razor with html, the pages can't adapt automatically. For me, the simplest fix was to change the content-type in the `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

The "figure out the content-type yourself" insanity only happens when nothing is set explicitly. So... set it.

Your actual views can still override this:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
}
```

For info, to test for this issue on your local dev server (with a clean cache to avoid false results by previous cached data), do something like wget or Fiddler:

```
wget yourpage --header="Accept: text/vnd.wap.wml" --server-response --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
```

and look for:

```
Content-Type: text/vnd.wap.wml; charset=utf-8
```

in the result; if you see that, IIS/ASP.NET has decided to pretend your reply satisfies the request's "Accept" header... even  if it doesn't. Worse: you might now be able to get that "text/vnd.wap.wml" from a wget **without** specifying the Accept header (or specifying something like "text/html"); if you see this ***you have a problem*** (or: your users do) - you have a cached response for WAP that is being fed to non-WAP clients.

With the above tweak, the first wget ***will return*** "text/html" - since that is what our content is. Sorry, down-level browsers; you should have included "text/html" as an option - and if you can't handle "text/html"... sucks to be you.

Answer (score 2):

using iis7. putting this is global.asax did the trick:

```
void Application_OnUpdateRequestCache() {
  if (Response.ContentType == "text/vnd.wap.wml") {
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
  }
}
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround (if you fail to manage to do configure the app), you could install wmlbrowser add-on for firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/62.

Comment: Does not really answer my question, but helps me solve my problem :) cheerio!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's more to do with your admin system that the IIS box as the admin site is seeing the useragent as a mobile device and changing how it renders your request, from standard HTML over to .wml. You will need to change this in the app I believe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That was my first idea also. But since I didn't find such thing in the code I created a new WebbApplication and tried it with a Nokia n95 user-agent and got the content as wml.   And if I try to browse SO with that user-agent I also get the response as text/vnd.wap.wml. which makes me think that asp.net use different contenttype for different user-agents.

Answer (score 0):

[Configure the MIME type](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true) for the wml extension to text/html.  You could also create a Custom [HTTPHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) and point the script map for the extension to ASP.NET. Then, you could check for the conditions you and force the rendering any way you want it.

Comment: I tried to change the Mime type on the webserver all thou I didn't seem to help. So I will try creating a custom HttpHandler

Answer (score 0):

You can override the server's behaviour with the [ClientTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx) property of the page.

In code:

```
Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
```

In the @ Page declaration:

```
<%@Page [...] clientTarget="uplevel" %>
```

Sadly, I don't think you can set this in the [pages element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx) of a web.config.

Comment: This does not fix the problem.