# ASP.NET cached pages forces you to download the HTML page

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7

I've got a high traffic blog (300,000 pageviews per day) made with asp.net that uses output cache for article pages.

It usually works well, but many users have complained about being prompted to download the page instead of being shown the page on the browser. I've seen it myself too a couple of times.. it goes away only when the cache for that page is refreshed.

It happens with II7 and below, using both .NET 4.0 and 2.0 (I recently updated the framework's version and the problem continues).

Any idea why?

Comment: It will help if you provide some code of the pages that have the problem, and also because is a random issue, is very difficult, you need to save and see what's exactly is the output when the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my problem.

In case anyone else is interested, the problem was that, sometimes, pages were cached after a request made by a mobile user. For some reason, IIS sends back the response type as WML instead of text/html in that case, which is only accepted by some mobile browsers, not desktop.

Here's the simple solution for it:
[Make IIS not render pages as WML. Ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261144/make-iis-not-render-pages-as-wml-ever/5909281#5909281)